# Insert a dos tablas en un controlador laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

Hola estoy tratando de ingresar datos a dos tablas diferentes por medio de laravel, los datos llegan de una vista, el problema es que me sale el siguiente error

The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: POST.

Al parecer segun lo que he preguntado se debe al request pero no estoy seguro, la primera parte que ingresa los datos a la tabla de usuarios funciona correctamente, al parecer el problema viene en el if. Adjunto el codigo de mi controlador:

```
public function RegistroCliente(Request $request)
{
    $validacion = Validator::make($request->all(),
    [

        'usuario' => 'required|max:50',
        'password' => 'required|min:6',
        'rol'=>'required',
        'cedula' => 'max:12',
        'celular'=> 'max:10',
        'ceco'=> '',
        'direccion' =>'',
        'lider' =>'',
        'lab_usu_id'=>''
    ]);

    if($validacion->fails())
    {
        return redirect('/registrar')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validacion);
    }

    $user=new tbl_usuario();
    $user->usuario=$request->usuario;
    $user->password=bcrypt($request->password);
    $user->rol=$request->rol;
    $user->cedula=$request->cedula;
    $user->celular=$request->celular;
    $user->save();



    //$credentials =DB::select("SELECT max(rol) FROM tbl_usuario");
    $credentials='Lab Catálisis';
    if ($credentials=='Lab Catálisis') {
        $lab=new tbl_lab();
        $lab->ceco=$request->ceco;
        $lab->direccion=$request->direccion;
        $lab->lider=$request->lider;
        $lab->lab_usu_id=DB::select("SELECT max(usu_id) FROM tbl_usuario");
        $lab->save();
        return view('login');
    }

}
```

La vista de donde envio los datos es la siguiente:

```
<form class="register-form" method="POST" action="{{ route('registro') }}" >
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Usuario</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="usuario" placeholder="Ingrese el usuario">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Contraseña</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Ingrese la contraseña">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="exampleFormControlSelect1" onclick="comprobar()">Seleccione el Rol
        <select class="form-control" id="rol" name="rol" required>
          <option value="1" >----</option>
          <option value="2">Lab Metrología</option>
          <option value="3">Lab Suelos</option>
          <option value="4">Lab Biotecnología</option>
          <option value="5">Lab Análisis petrofísicos</option>
          <option >Lab Catálisis</option>
        </select>
      </label>


      <p id="datos" style="visibility: hidden;">
        <label>

          <label>CECO</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ceco" placeholder="Ingrese el codigo ceco">

          <label>Direccion</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="direccion" placeholder="Ingrese la dirección">

          <label>Lider</label>
          <input type="text" class="form-control" name="lider" placeholder="Ingrese el nombre del lider">

        </label>
      </p>
      </div>
      <div class="form-check">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-register float-right">Registrar</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Y la ruta es la siguiente:

```
Route::post('/registrar','registroController@RegistroCliente')->name('registro');
```

Gracias.

Comment: Muéstranos tus rutas, a la que redireccionas cuando falla la validación y la que corresponde a la vista desde donde envías los datos.

Comment: Ya hice la corrección a esas te refieres?

Comment: Sí, y también debes tener una ruta GET que corresponde con la vista donde tienes el formulario. Entonces al hacer el redirect, debes hacerlo a la ruta GET y no a esa que muestras, que es POST

Comment: Cree otra ruta GET la cual me lleva a la vista, y lo cambien en el redirect, cuando voy a hacer el registro a darle registrar pues me redirecciona a la misma vista, entonces el fallo esta en la validación no?

Comment: La validación falla porque los datos del request no cumplen con las reglas y por eso entra en el if donde está el redirect, pero eso es otro tema. Lo que tienes que tener en cuenta aquí es que estabas intentando redireccionar a la misma ruta que te llevó a ese método del controlador, lo cual no tiene sentido. Tendrías que redireccinar a la ruta que te lleva a la vista con el formulario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En el único sitio donde veo que puede haber complicaciones de ese tipo es en la condición:

```
if($validacion->fails())
    {
        return redirect('/registrar')
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validacion);
    }
```

Si debería echar para atrás deberías hacer algo así:

```
if($validacion->fails())
    {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput()
            ->withErrors($validacion);
    }
```

El error es debido a que en tu tabla de enrutación (routes/web.php) la ruta "registrar" será algo asi:

```
Route::post('registrar' , 'Controller@method');
```

Y al hacer un redirect a una ruta, se hace con get por lo general

Espero que te funcione! ;)